# Google map API v2. How to custom another marker like foodspotting app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I am developing an android app. I am using google map API v2. But I don't use default icon marker. How can I using marker like same foodspotting app. 
I must design marker in xxdpi, xdpi, hdpi or another other way?

I don't know how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
      BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.pin_red);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(78.55, 244.67);
        // Setting the position for the marker
       markerOptions.position(latLng);
// setting the icon
             markerOptions.icon(icon);
```

where pin_red is your .png image

Comment: Hi jyomin ! But the image too large ! I don't know size !

Comment: you have to design the image for the same...In mdpi use 32X21 pixels size

Comment: for xhdpi use 72X86 pixels size for width and height

Comment: 108X129 for xxhdpi and 49X59 for hdpi

Answer (score 0):

you have to read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker).
add marker like this

```
 static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(MELBOURNE)
                          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

also you add different [shapes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes)

Comment: Hi lmtiyaz ! Thank you ! I will read it